# Rails 3 validations problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

In my form I would like users to type a date in DD/MM/YYYY format. I have validation that checks that.

The problem is that in the database it is stored in YYYY-MM-DD format, so if try just to update the `is_money_paid` field:

```
job = Job.find(params[:id])
job.update_attributes(:is_money_paid => ...)
```

the validation fails saying that job's date is in wrong format (YYYY-MM-DD rather than DD/MM/YYYY).

What would be an appropriate way to solve this ?

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :job_date_validator
end

DATE_REGEX = /\A\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\z/

def job_date_validator
  if job_date_before_type_cast.blank?
    errors.add(:job_date, "^Date must be selected")
  elsif job_date_before_type_cast !~ DATE_REGEX
    errors.add(:job_date, "^Date must be in DD/MM/YYYY format")
  end
end
```

`is_money_paid` is a boolean field.

Comment: 1. show your validation code; 2. what `is_money_paid` column type is

Comment: Maybe you can turn the dates in before_validation  ???

Comment: I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the validator to say:

```
validate_presence_of :job_date, :message => "must be selected"
validate :job_date_validator, :if => :job_date_changed?
```

Or something along those lines.

You can take out the .blank? check too.

Comment: What should `job_date_before_type_cast_changed?` do ? Is it Rails method, or I should define it ?

Comment: assuming that `job_date_before_type_cast` is an attribute in the database for your model, then rails defines the `*_changed?` method for you which returns `true` if the field has been altered, but the value has not yet been saved to the database.

Comment: Actually, `job_date` is the name of the attribute. `job_date_before_type_cast` is created by Rails. Could you give me a pointer to `*_changed?` documentation please ?

Comment: Hard to find documentation on method_missing dynamic methods.  But I did find this:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/attribute_changed%3F  `attribute_changed?` is a private method, but it handles the `*_changed?` methods from method_missing

Comment: @Misha I updated the answer... didn't realize rails gives you a `*_before_type_cast` method, I think in your case just `:job_date_changed?` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Format it in before_validation

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#updating-an-object

Comment: But, if I convert the date from **YYYY-MM-DD** to **DD/MM/YYYY** in `before_validation`, then the user will be able to insert the date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format. Isn't it ?

Comment: not sure I follow.  this doesn't impact what the user can enter, only what will be saved.  if you want the ui to always display in a particular format, then you should do that in a helper method at the display layer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to see gem [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) which is rails 3 compatible.